# I have to change date format to DD/yy/mm

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-modal

Links to Code:
[ASP File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz61k.png)
[C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFrTt.png)

I have to change date format to DD/yy/mm. What changes should I make in JS file. I tried changing the format in C# code. But I did not get the required output.

Comment: DD should be dd? and what output did you get?

Comment: and `mm` should be `MM`, take look [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) for more date formating option

Answer (score 0):

txt_fromdate.Text = mydate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

So you know how to do formatting DateTime Object to display them in certain formats. The issues is with the format that you are trying. In the case of dateTime formating we will use `m` to represent minute whereas `M` is for `Month` likewise we won't use `D` instead for that we will use `d` to represent day. so you have to try `"dd/yy/MM"` instead for `MM/dd/yyyy` to get date in `"dd/yy/MM"` format

```
txtFromDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/yy/MM");
```

Answer (score 0):

On server side - `yourfielld.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/yy/MM");`

By javascript :-

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/yy/MM"});
  });
  </script>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="datepicker" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```